# How to use STL in PNACL C++ code

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am working on PNACL project, i wanted to use STL in my project basically to use the collection, algorithms provided by STL.

I see the STL header files present in toolchain folders. but header files are different for each platform(like x86,x64 and ARM). but PNACL project should work on platform independence.

I am using visual studio as IDE.

thanks
Venkat.

Answer (score 1):

The PNaCl C++ compiler, `pnacl-clang++`, uses the version of libc++ that's distributed with the SDK. The compiler finds this STL implementation automatically and will include the headers and link the static library for it automatically, without you having to specify anything. If you do try to specify the path to another STL then things may indeed go very badly!

The IDE that you use shouldn't matter, but you'll have to either invoke `pnacl-clang++` from the command-line, or get the IDE to invoke that compiler correctly.

The other platforms you see supported may be for NaCl's (not PNaCl's) sake, but without more information on what you're looking at it's hard to tell.

Did you just try compiling code? Did that work, and if not how?